# Multiple ids and an unique name

Tags: javascript, json, ruby-on-rails-3.2, coffeescript

I am very new in Ruby and JavaScript, so I not sure about what I am doing. I have a dropdown box that I would like to show by unique name.

1. I use JavaScript(CoffeeScript) to get the results with JSON
2. I created a method to show by unique name (It is working)

My problem is how can I get both ids? When I select a object the value is the id, and the text method is the name. For example, if I have 3 objects with the same name, I need to get three ids. Now, I am getting just one.

Is there another way to do it? Thanks a lot!

```
TABLE OBJECTS

ID
NAME (I have duplicates in name)
MODEL

UNIQUE INDEX (NAME, MODEL)
```

Comment: What is id? Is it an html id? You cannot have duplicates

Comment: the id is the primary key in the table objects. I just have duplicates in name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to do your select based on the name of the object. Something like

```
MyModel.find_by_name(params[:name])
```

This will require you to send the `name` of the item to the server instead of the `id`. You are probably currently doing something like

```
MyModel.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: My problem is that I cannot change the attribute that the field sent. For example, it sent the id, but I cannot change to the name because I have several dependent things. :(
I tried to get the id, go to the database, get the name, search for the name, and get the ids. [It works!] However, I just can do it, after the append method. I was looking for a way to do it in the append because I need that id for another dropdown.

Comment: Then do that you said. `my_model = MyModel.find(params[:id]); @my_models = MyModel.find_by_name(my_model.name)`